# What are the different (int routes) values for setAudioRoute (int routes)?

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, speaker, audio-source

Where can I find a list for the different "int routes" available for the following functions :

```
setAudioRoute (int routes)
```

or

```
setRouting (int mode, int routes, int mask)
```

I would like to find a list with the different int like :

1 = speakers

2 = bluetooth

3 = headphones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the possible audio routes in this documentation: [CallAudioState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallAudioState?hl=en#constants_1)

I have found the best way to find this is using the documentation in the actual code. If you go inside the file look at the documentation for that function its:

```
   /**
     * Sets the audio route (speaker, bluetooth, etc...).  When this request is honored, there will
     * be change to the {@link #getCallAudioState()}.
     * <p>
     * Used by self-managed {@link ConnectionService}s which wish to change the audio route for a
     * self-managed {@link Connection} (see {@link PhoneAccount#CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED}.)
     * <p>
     * See also {@link InCallService#setAudioRoute(int)}.
     *
     * @param route The audio route to use (one of {@link CallAudioState#ROUTE_BLUETOOTH},
     *              {@link CallAudioState#ROUTE_EARPIECE}, {@link CallAudioState#ROUTE_SPEAKER}, or
     *              {@link CallAudioState#ROUTE_WIRED_HEADSET}).
     */
    public final void setAudioRoute(int route) {
        for (Listener l : mListeners) {
            l.onAudioRouteChanged(this, route, null);
        }
    }
```